# Why isnt my for loop of objects printing out?

Tags: java, arrays, object, arraylist

I feel like this is somewhat right to at least print out the toString method of each subclass but for some reason its resulting in nothing being printed whatsoever. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

data.txt:

```
1 meter
1 inch
1 foot
1 yard
401.336 meters
15839 inches
1319 feet
439 yards
```

code

```
public abstract class Length implements Comparable<Length> {

    public String toString() {
        return this.getClass() + ": " + getLength() + " " + getUnit();
    }



public static void main(String[] args){
        ArrayList<Length> lo = new ArrayList <Length>();
        Scanner in = null;
        try {
            in = new Scanner(new File("src/length/data.txt"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException exception) {
            throw new RuntimeException("failed to open data.txt");
        }
        // need more code for other parts of this assignment
        while (in.hasNextDouble()) {
            double value = in.nextDouble();
            String unit = in.next();
            Length length = null;

            if(unit.equals("Meter")){
                length = new Meter(value);
                lo.add(length);             
            }

            else if(unit.equals("Foot")){

                length = new Foot(value);
                lo.add(length);
            }

            else if(unit.equals("Inch")){
                length= new Inch(value);
                lo.add(length);
            }

            else if(unit.equals("Yard")){
                length = new Yard(value);
                lo.add(length);
            }

        }
        Length[] myLengths = new Length[lo.size()]; //declares myLengths integer array 
        for(int i=0; i < lo.size(); i++){       
            myLengths[i]=lo.get(i);     //copies arrayList to lo to Length array myLengths

        }


    for(int i = 0; i < myLengths.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(myLengths[i].toString());  
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: What does your file contain? Seems like `myLengths.length` is 0.

Comment: this is the contents of data.txt 1 meter
1 inch
1 foot
1 yard
401.336 meters
15839 inches
1319 feet
439 yards

Comment: Don't post it here. Edit your question and add it there, formatted.

Comment: What your `toString()` method looks like in class `Length`?

Comment: `myLengths = lo.toArray()` eliminates the need for a for loop to create an array

Comment: BTW, the last two for-loops are redundant: you can use `toArray()` and `Arrays.toString()` (assuming `Length` overrides `toString`)

Comment: @RickGarcia, ur if..else won't work if ur input file contains units in lower case. bcoz "Meter" is not "meter" n "meters" in java.

Comment: Your values in code don't match the file values. `Meter` vs `meters` and `meter`. You never add anything to the `ArrayList`.

Comment: such a sill mistake! Arvind and Sotirios thank you ! and thanks to everyone else for the speedy responses. Im so focused on trying to understand this inheritance stuff that I over look the smallest thing!

Comment: inside your file the unit is in small case like 'feet', 'meter' etc. but you are comparing it with "Feet" [first case large]. Please use equalsIgnoreCase instead of equals.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in this code is the string comparison. Instead of unit.equals("Inch"), please use unit.equalsIgnoreCase("Inch") etc. Corrected code:

```
public abstract class Length implements Comparable<Length> {

    public String toString() {
        return this.getClass() + ": " + getLength() + " " + getUnit();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Length> lo = new ArrayList<Length>();
        Scanner in = null;
        try {
            in = new Scanner(new File("src/length/data.txt"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException exception) {
            throw new RuntimeException("failed to open data.txt");
        }
        // need more code for other parts of this assignment
        while (in.hasNextDouble()) {
            double value = in.nextDouble();
            String unit = in.next();
            Length length = null;

            if (unit.equalsIgnoreCase("Meter")) {
                length = new Meter(value);
                lo.add(length);
            } else if (unit.equalsIgnoreCase("Foot")) {

                length = new Foot(value);
                lo.add(length);
            } else if (unit.equalsIgnoreCase("Inch")) {
                length = new Inch(value);
                lo.add(length);
            } else if (unit.equalsIgnoreCase("Yard")) {
                length = new Yard(value);
                lo.add(length);
            }

        }
        Length[] myLengths = new Length[lo.size()]; //declares myLengths integer array 
        for (int i = 0; i < lo.size(); i++) {
            myLengths[i] = lo.get(i);     //copies arrayList to lo to Length array myLengths

        }


        for (int i = 0; i < myLengths.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(myLengths[i].toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there are two problems in your code in the unit string comparison.

1. other answers have mentioned, in code you are using "Inch" while in file you are using "inch".  It can be solved by using `equalsIgnoreCase()`
2. Even you made the change of 1, you will still face problem of reading incomplete file.  The reason is in the file, you will encounter both singular and plural unit name.  It can be solved by doing somehting like `if (unit.equalsIgnoreCase("foot") || unit.equalsIgnoreCase("feet"))`